# On error skip to next

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

I am trying to get some text between two words from a column of similar data, so far I have:

```
Dim I As Integer

For I = 1 To 989

thisSTRING = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & I).Value
ref = Split(Split(thisSTRING, "RING ")(1), " EM")(0)
Worksheets(1).Range("B" & I).Value = ref

Next I
```

The problem I have is that not all text in the column is the same and when I reach such a point in the for loop I get an error message as there is either no "RING" or "EM", to avoid this I tried to use "on error resume next". This worked but it duplicates in the cells which had the errors. Is there any simple method for making this skip the cell/leave it blank instead of creating a duplicate?

Comment: Test for the presence of both before doing the split. If they're not present, then the cell = "".

Comment: Is there a simple command to check the presence or would I have to do something like loop through the string and find the words?

Comment: I have done it. Could you please submit an answer so that I can choose it as best answer?

Comment: Glad it worked! I can't do it now, but will try later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I was thinking:

```
Sub PrintSplit()
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim thisSTRING As String
Dim ref As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
For i = 1 To 989
    thisSTRING = ws.Range("A" & i).Value
    If InStr(thisSTRING, "RING ") > 0 And InStr(thisSTRING, " EM") > 0 Then
        ref = Split(Split(thisSTRING, "RING ")(1), " EM")(0)
        ws.Range("B" & i).Value = ref
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This assumes that you want a blank if either of the strings are missing. If you only wanted it if both strings are missing the logic would be different, but similar.

Note that I changed `i` to a `Long` which is a good practice, as it's the native type for whole numbers and will accommodate larger values. I also created a `worksheet` variable, just to make it a little more flexible, and to get Intellisense.